# Gradle dependency in library being shadowed by Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, groovy, dependency-management

The scenario. I write LibraryA which needs to use a newer version of a library (Caffeine in this case, and specifically v2.6.2). I will build and upload this artifact to our build artifactory

LibraryA is intended to be used by other teams (unknown to me) in an older Spring Boot 1.5 environment . The issue is that Spring Boot internally uses an older version of Caffeine 2.3.5 (although to me , it could use a newer one).

What I see is at runtime, the older version dominates the newer version resulting in class not found exceptions in my lib

Is there a way, I can force my library to always use the newer desired Caffeine version . This would be easy to do if I had control over the code using my library but I'd like to accomplish this within the scope of my library. I tried all the dependency resolution strategies in the gradle documentaion but they are always overridden by the invoking (spring-boot) application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use package relocating from [gradle shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/).

In your case you just add following to your build:

```
shadowJar {
   relocate 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine', 'shadow.caffeine'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but the packages are not relocated
`
shadowJar {
baseName = 'shadow-wrapped'
version = null
zip64 true
relocate 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine', 'shadow-wrapped.caffeine'
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
`

but looking at the generated jar, ..nothing has been relocated

`
$ jar -tf shadow-wrapped-all.jar  |grep -i caf
com/github/benmanes/caffeine/
com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/
......
`

Comment: Ok, worked , I had to use `relocate 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine', 'shadow.caffeine'` (remove the dash between ben and manes - as that doesn't exist in the actual directory pkg structure

Comment: Sorry for that and thanks for the remark I fixed my answer. I'm glad it worked.